# Clustering behaviour buggy on mobile devices

Tags: cluster-analysis, here-api, marker

i'm having trouble getting the clustering technique working on mobile and desktop devices equivalently.

The problem is well seen in the here maps examples at https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/clustering/marker-clustering

Resolving all clusters at max zoom works well on desktop browsers. While on mobile devices e.g. IOS 12 Safari browser won't resolve all clusters when max zoom is reached.

Further more if i attach a tap event to clustering provider like (or in traditional way)

```
fromEvent(this.chargingstationCluster.provider, 'tap').subscribe((event: H.util.Event) => {

    try {
      event.target.getData().isCluster();
      this.map.setViewBounds(event.target.getData().getBounds(), true);

    } catch (e) {
    }

  })
```

On mobile devices the cluster does not get resolved, instead it is only repositioned to center.

Any hints or solutions on this?

**edit
Actually found out that mobile devices do not zoom to configured max zoom level.
E.g. having Max-Zoom level configured to 19, the ios devices only zooms to max 17.415037499278842

Answer (score 0):

So actually mobile devices loose 1.584962500721158 points when calculating max zoom. 
Adding 1.584962500721158 to max zoom finally leads to a max zoom of 19